# StringEntity not stringifying content on print or socket write

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I have some json I'm trying to return as part of a BasicHttpResponse. 
A code snippit is below and I've annotated the resulting printouts.

I can print out the json in A and it looks good in 1. But when I print the entity at B I don't get any body in 2, though it does have the length. If I go into the debugger I see the data there.

If I change the content type and print the entity I can see that this change is reflected in 3 but again no actual String data.

I'm trying to push this data through a pipe and not getting the json body on a write is a bit of a problem.

My expectation is that when I add data to an entity and then print or write the entity using a HttpMessageWriter that the json would be shown/transferred. What am I missing? Is it unreasonable to expect the json to be printed on a toString?

```
     BasicHttpResponse resp;
     StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF-8");
A)   logger.info("to str: " + json.toString());
B)   logger.info("Entity: " + entity);
     entity.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
     resp.setEntity(entity);
C)   logger.info("set entity " + resp.getEntity());



1)  to str: [{"id":"12","revision":"12","group":"12",
              "remote":"12"}]
2)  Entity: [Content-Type: text/plain; 
          charset=UTF-8,Content-Length: 81,Chunked: false]
3)  set entity [Content-Type: application/json; 
             charset=UTF-8,Content-Length: 81,Chunked: false]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The toString() method from StringEntity will only print the data that you are getting, that is the correct behaviour.

The String given to StringEntity is saved as a byte array in the object.

This is the constructor for StringEntity:

```
/**
 * Creates a StringEntity with the specified content and content type.
 *
 * @param string content to be used. Not {@code null}.
 * @param contentType content type to be used. May be {@code null}, in which case the default
 *   MIME type {@link ContentType#TEXT_PLAIN} is assumed.
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the string parameter is null
 * @throws UnsupportedCharsetException Thrown when the named charset is not available in
 * this instance of the Java virtual machine
 * @since 4.2
 */
public StringEntity(final String string, final ContentType contentType) throws UnsupportedCharsetException {
    super();
    Args.notNull(string, "Source string");
    Charset charset = contentType != null ? contentType.getCharset() : null;
    if (charset == null) {
        charset = HTTP.DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET;
    }
    this.content = string.getBytes(charset);
    if (contentType != null) {
        setContentType(contentType.toString());
    }
}
```

If you want to print your entity as json again (for logging for example, since it's already being set in the response) you have to do something like:

```
logger.info("Entity: " + IOUtils.toString(entity.getContent()));
```

Using IOUtils.toString since entity.getContent() brings an InputStream object, you can use it as you wish.

Comment: Thanks. There's always one more problem to solve. I thought this was the simple version but the data isn't being sent over the socket either. I'll try to track it down and update the question or ask a new one.

Comment: Yes, that is most likely an entirely different problem :) Good luck :)